# Python 3.2 Logging handlers 'nonetype object has no attribute setLevel()'

Tags: python

I followed the documentation as carefully, but somehow creating the handler doesnt seem to be working.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create handlers and set levels
qaHandler = logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('%sQA.log'%__name__,when='midnight', backupCount=3))
qaHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Thats the code, what have I missed?

Comment: `addHandler()` does not return the  handler but `None`.

Comment: Okay, I spose thats what I get for blindly fixing errors as they come up. How can i reference the handler? Do I need to create it first then use addHandler()?

Comment: Yes, put it into a variable, the use the variable to add it.

Comment: Okay, thats working now. Thank you!

Comment: @KlausD. - Please turn your comment into an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: @user3593486 - Once Klaus D. has given an answer, please accept the answer by clicking on its checkmark, then edit your title to remove the word "[Solved]". On this website, we prefer to use the accepted-answer mechanism to mark solved problems: it shows up in a different color in question lists, and on questions with multiple answers, it makes it clear *which* answer solved the problem. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addHandler()` does not return the handler but `None`. Put the handler into a variable, then use the variable to add it.

Comment: Can you update that solution with a sample?